# Image gallery broken as "slideSwitch is not defined" :-(

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

I'm just starting to learn Jquery, and have done a few tutorials, frustratingly, this one is one of the most basic I've done, and I can't seem to get it working.

This is the tutorial I'm following:- http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

When I start the page up, and run debug in Chrome and firebug in firefox I get the error:- 
   "**Uncaught ReferenceError: slideSwitch is not defined**"

This is my code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function slideSwitch(){
       var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
       var $next = $active.next();

       $active.addClass('last-active');

       $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
         .addClass('active')
         .animate({opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
              $active.removeClass('active last-active');
         });
  }
  $(function (){
      setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
  });
});
```

As far as I can tell, I've defined the function slideSwitch correctly, and no one else in the comments box has had this problem. I'm sure its something really simple I'm doing wrong.

Comment: are you sure you have to call setInterval that way? From what I see, it would be better to use `setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);` as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Window.setInterval

Comment: Try removing all the stuff from slideSwitch and just add an alert in there. If it works, then the problem is inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your `slideSwitch` function isn't defined in the global scope (only inside that `.ready()` hadler), and when you pass a **string** to `setInterval()` that's where it's looking, instead do this:

```
$(function(){
   function slideSwitch(){
       var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
       var $next = $active.next();

       $active.addClass('last-active');

       $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
         .addClass('active')
         .animate({opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
              $active.removeClass('active last-active');
         });
  }
  setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );
});
```

For the record, this would still work (where you have it, since it's in a parent scope):

```
$(function (){
  setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});
```

But...you're already in a `document.ready` handler, so there's no need for the wrapper here.